# solving the following integration

Tags: calculus, integration

I have the following integration

$\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b}\frac{f^{'}\left(s\right)}{cf\left(s\right)-d}\ \text{d}s$

where $c$ and $d$ are constants.

The first thing which comes to my mind is using the usual $\int_{a}^{b}\frac{u^{'}(s)}{u(s)}\ \text{d}s=\ln u\left(b\right)-\ln u\left(a\right)$ 
but I don't know how to find the primitive of the integration above.
Could you give me some hints or solution ?

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider if the integrand is a function of the form $\frac{d}{ds}\ln(cf(s)-d)$?

Answer (score 1):

$\int_a^b \frac{f'(s)ds}{cf(s)-d} = \frac{1}{c} \int_a^b \frac{f'(s)ds}{f(s)-\frac{d}{c}}.$

Now you can use the relation (which follows from the chain rule): $\frac{f'(s)}{f(s)-k}= \frac{d}{ds}(ln(f(s)-k))$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume the integral is convergent. We may write
$$
\int_{a}^{b}\frac{f'\left(s\right)}{cf\left(s\right)-d}ds= \frac1c\int_{a}^{b}\frac{(cf\left(s\right)-d)'}{cf\left(s\right)-d}ds=\frac1c \left[\log |cf\left(s\right)-d|\right]_{s=a}^{s=b}.
$$